# Use * (asterix) as a term query in Elastic search

Tags: php, elasticsearch, lucene

I have a document with a tag '*'

Yet when I construct a term query it returns no results. How can I query documents with the tag '*'. My guess is it's a special character that needs to be escaped.

**Update with answer**

I needed to set the property to not analyzed so that elastic search wouldn't strip out punctuation etc.

```
$myTypeMapping = array(
    '_source' => array(
        'enabled' => true
    ),
    'properties' => array(
        'tag' => array("type" => "string", "index" => "not_analyzed")
    )
);
$indexParams['body']['mappings']['file'] = $myTypeMapping;
```

Comment: in theory `\*` should find `*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `tag` field is analyzed then the the star is not indexed. See for yourself:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=standard' -d '*'
```

Response:

```
{"tokens":[]}
```

You will need to change the field to not_analyzed or to change the analyzer.